# Mounting samba share loses file ownership info

Tags: networking, server, samba, cifs, domain-server

I'm setting up a small domain. The AD DC runs samba 4.11.6 on Ubuntu 20.04. I wanted that samba instance to also host a cifs share for user homes that I could mount on client machines. So I figured I'd create `/home/MYDOMAIN` directory and all domain users' homes would be inside that. Then I'd expose this as a network share on the AD DC and mount it on client machines in the same location - `/home/MYDOMAIN` — so that users who log on with domain credentials would automatically find their home directory mounted. This is the `smb.conf` that achieves that:

```
[global]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        dns forwarder = 192.168.1.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        netbios name = ADDC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        realm = MYDOMAIN.COM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        server role = active directory domain controller                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        workgroup = MYDOMAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        vfs objects = dfs_samba4 acl_xattr recycle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        map acl inherit = Yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        template shell = /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        template homedir = /home/%D/%U  
[users]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        comment = User home directories                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        path = /home/MYDOMAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        browseable = Yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        guest ok = No                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        create mask = 0640                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        directory mask = 0750                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        writeable = Yes
```

This is all fine and well except one detail. If I now specify the following on a domain member PC, also running Ubuntu 20.04, in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//addc.mydomain.com/users    /home/MYDOMAIN  cifs    credentials=/root/.administratorcredentials,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8     0       0
```

When I mount this with `mount -a`, I get `/home/MYDOMAIN` directory that is owned by root:root. Everything under that, including the users' home directories, is also owned by root:root which means users won't be able to write to their homes unless I make everything writable by everyone, which kinda defeats the purpose of setting up this domain to begin with.

I read that when setting up samba as AD DC, it's file sharing capabilities are somewhat limited to only supporting Windows ACLs, but not POSIX. Is this what is happening here? Am I losing that ownership info because of this? When I inspect the shared directories on a Windows 10 machine, they seem to be owned by whom they should be.

Is there any workaround for this or maybe a better idea to achieve the same - only maintain one copy of the domain users' home directories?

------------------ EDIT 31.10.2020 --------------------

After loads of further digging I found the possible cause of why my original config wouldn't work, but am yet to find a solution. Could it be because my idmap isn't setup correctly (or at all in fact)? The reason I say this is that when I say the following on the ad dc:

```
id myuser@mydomain.com
```

I get a response that contains uid=3000034 and gid=100(users). But on the other PC, the domain member that I joined through sssd, the same command yields a response with uid=1001801118 and gid=1001800513(domain users@mydomain.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of [users]

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
```

You will have to manually create each users homedir under /home/MYDOMAIN, or write a 'root preexec' script to create them as the user connects to the share.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as per the samba wiki pages, [homes] isn't supported on a samba instance running as active directory domain controller.

Comment: It lies, I must update that page. What you cannot do is use posix acls,

Comment: OK, I have updated the wikipage.

Comment: I will try this over the weekend, with my fallback option being an NFS share out of samba. Thanks for Your help thus far, I'll report back here whether it worked.

Comment: So I tried this solution out and it kinda works, but doesn't do what I need. It exposes the directory only of the user currently logged into samba, like this (both are actually the same folder under the hood):

\\addc.mydomain.com\homes

\\addc.mydomain.com\<username>

but this means two things:
1) I need to be a logged in user or provide the password at mount time
2) I cannot do this at boot time because at that point no domain user is logged on yet so the

Comment: Unless your other computer is running a version of Samba before 4.8.0, then you cannot use sssd with Samba any longer, you must use winbind. A Samba AD DC uses xidNumber attributes stored in idmap.ldb, these are all in the'3000000' range (except for 3, one of which is '100' which is mapped to the 'users' group). If you are logging in via something like lightdm, then PAM can pass the user and password down the stack to something like pam_mount.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow now - I managed to join the domain (I did re-provision it from scratch using --use-rfc2307) from clients using ssd, and using ad as source of uid and gid, by switching off idmap on clients I arrived in a situation wher uids and gids on the ad dc and on domain clients match perfectly. And yet the shared folders are still root-owned. I found information elsewhere that in fact sssd is the recommended client software over winbind nowadays. Are You saying the opposite?

Comment: Yes, if you using Samba 4.8.0 or greater, with 'security = ADS' in smb.conf, then you MUST run winbind and you CANNOT run winbind and sssd at the same time. If you can point me to wherever you found where it says that using sssd is the recommended client  software, I will contact them and point out just where they are going wrong, as not even red-hat supports using sssd with Samba.

Comment: I'm on 4.11.6 as stated in the original post, and sssd works fine on client machines. Having said that, here's a link to somewhere they claim sssd is better than winbind:
```https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/8ku7qo/winbind_or_sssd_for_samba_ad_member_and_why/```
Think I saw similar arguments elsewhere too, but can't re-find it. Are You saying if I switch to winbind that'll fix the user and group ownership on my shared home folders? The [homes] solution doesn't quite cut it for me because I'd have to defer mounting till logon time.Kinda hurts my sense of aesthetic to do it that way

Comment: so I've made some decent progress using [homes] and pam_mount but there's still an issue that's preventing it from functioning as it should. When I mount at logon using pam_mount the client machine sees all files and directories owned and group owned by uid and gid that is correct. But when I create or even modify a file, back on the server this looks like it was added or changed by an administrator. It's causing some very weird behavior from programs that need to write their files in user's home directory.Is this because of not using winbind? uid and gid numbers match between client and ad-dc

Comment: Yes, apart from not working with winbind, sssd does not do NTLM and ACLs.

Comment: So I managed to re-join one of my domain member PCs using winbind instead of sssd, but this hasn't really solved the file ownership problem on the network mounted volume. Even when I set up winbind to use ad as idmap backend, the client sees file ownership correctly, but back on the server the new files are created owned by BUILTIN\Administrators and group-owned by users - I think the default local group. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You appear to be running into one of the many reasons why we do not recommend using a Samba AD DC as a fileserver. It can be used, but there are numerous reasons why you shouldn't. Could you run a separate Unix domain member (perhaps in a VM) ?

Comment: In the end I decided to roll with NFS-exported share for user homes, that seems to work as expected (kerberos authentication yet to be done here, but since I'm using AD as idmap backend on member PCs, that's ok for now). I don't want to spin up a VM just to run samba because I already have to spin up another VM for my work stuff. 
However, I had a very interesting twist of events yesterday and I'm still trying to figure out what happened there:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292869/samba-ad-dc-no-longer-accepts-login-using-domain-accounts
Probably some rogue update pulled in by ubuntu...