# Samba AD DC no longer accepts login using domain accounts

Tags: login, password, samba, pam, active-directory

I've been trying to setup Samba AD DC on Ubuntu 20.04 for a good while now and with some success. I use the server which runs this Samba instance as my primary workstation, so I need to be able to log on to it using domain accounts, and up until today I was able to do so. In all honesty I can't think of what I broke because it just stopped - my screen got locked through inactivity, and when I tried to unlock it the machine refused my correct password. It did allow me to log on locally but then the server demanded a reboot. And I haven't been able to log on using domain accounts eversince. This is so strange because domain member PCs (Ubuntu 20.04 as well) can login using domain accounts without issues, albeit they do so via SSSD and not winbind. I thought maybe the AD database got corrupted during the somewhat hardcore reboot, but if that were the case I reckon members wouldn't be able to log users on as well, right?

Here are a few config snippets:

**/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
# Global parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[global]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        dns forwarder = 192.168.1.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        netbios name = PRIMARYDC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        realm = MYDOM.COM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        server role = active directory domain controller                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        workgroup = MYDOM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        vfs objects = dfs_samba4 acl_xattr recycle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = Yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        template shell = /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        template homedir = /home/%D/%U                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        unix extensions = Yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        winbind enum users = Yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        winbind enum groups = Yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        winbind use default domain = Yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        log level = 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[sysvol]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        read only = No                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[netlogon]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/mydom.com/scripts                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        read only = No
```

**/etc/nssswitch.conf**

```
passwd:         files systemd winbind                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
group:          files systemd winbind                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
shadow:         files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
gshadow:        files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
networks:       files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
protocols:      db files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
services:       db files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ethers:         db files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
rpc:            db files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
netgroup:       nis
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-password**

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
password        [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000                                                                                                                                                                                                          
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512                                                                                                                                                                                 
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_winbind.so try_authtok try_first_pass                                                                                                                                                                                             
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# since the modules above will each just jump around                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
password        required                        pam_permit.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
password        optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-auth**

```
uth    [success=3 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass                                                                                                                                                                                                      
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass                                                                                                                                                                    
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# since the modules above will each just jump around                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
auth    required                        pam_permit.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-session**

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
session requisite                       pam_deny.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# since the modules above will each just jump around                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
session required                        pam_permit.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# The pam_umask module will set the umask according to the system default in                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# /etc/login.defs and user settings, solving the problem of different                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# umask settings with different shells, display managers, remote sessions etc.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# See "man pam_umask".                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
session optional                        pam_umask.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
session optional                        pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
session required        pam_unix.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
session optional                        pam_winbind.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
session optional        pam_systemd.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
session optional                        pam_mkhomedir.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-account**

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so                                                                                                                                                                                                           
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_winbind.so                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
account requisite                       pam_deny.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# since the modules above will each just jump around                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
account required                        pam_permit.so                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
account required                        pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
# end of pam-auth-update config                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
session required                        pam_mkhomedir.so        skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
```

On the AD DC I can retrieve users using `wbinfo -u`. Using samba-tool to retrieve user info also gives me all information on my users. However trying `getent passwd MYDOM\\someuser` gives me nothing while `getent group MYDOM\\somegroup` gives me correct info for the said group except it's members - the list is empty. On member PCs all of these work fine and `getent group` returns full lists of users. Any hints as to what may be wrong here would be greatly appreciated. I'm guessing this is something to do with nssswitch and pam modules, but I can't currently figure out what is misconfigured. Interestingly enough, I have a Windows 10 PC at home connected to this domain as well, and I can log on using domain accounts on that one too...

Comment: My first thought is, has your password expired ? My second thought is, why are you using a Samba AD DC as a workstation ? Also most of the lines you have added to your smb.conf can be removed, they are doing nothing.

Comment: I'm using my home server as a workstation because simply speaking I can't afford to have them separated :) Password hasn't expired, I was getting a prompt at logon that it will happen in 26 days or so before everything broke down. When You say most lines in smb.conf, which ones are those? I reckon at least some are necessary, but I'm all in for making stuff work by removing code, not by adding more of it :)

Comment: You are not using 'recycle', so you do not need this line:
        vfs objects = dfs_samba4 acl_xattr recycle                                                                                                                                                                                           
These are the defaults, so not required:
        template homedir = /home/%D/%U
        unix extensions = Yes
These do nothing but slow things down:
        winbind enum users = Yes
        winbind enum groups = Yes
This doesn't do anything on a DC:
        winbind use default domain = Yes

Comment: Could you run the DC in a VM on your computer and then use the computer as a Unix domain member ? BIG NOTE: you cannot use sssd with Samba >= 4.8.0, you must use winbind.

Comment: You see this is the part I really don't understand - I'm running AD DC on Samba 4.11.6 and for the love of me I wasn't able to reliably connect any domain client pc with winbind - it would come and go, couldn't be trusted. On the other hand sssd just works out of the box, no issues observed as yet. Why can't I use it, if people can use it to connect to AD DC running on windows servers? Isn't Samba implementing the same protocols?

Comment: No, Samba doesn't implement the same protocols, it implements more. sssd uses some of the winbind libs, so you cannot use it on a a Samba DC. If you do not believe me, then perhaps you will believe Red-Hat: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/smb-sssd I suggest you come and talk to me on the samba mailing list.